# How do I iterate over a tree in rails and make sure that the parents of all child nodes are selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called Service which has a many-to-many relationship with a model called Category.

Categories themselves exist in a hierarchy tree: parent categories can have several levels of grandchildren. I'm using the [closure tree](https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree) gem to handle this.

In my situation, it doesn't make sense for a service to be in a child category without also being in all its parents, but I'm having trouble enforcing this on a model level.

I think a `before_save` active record callback on the service model could do what I need, but I'm not sure how to write the code in the most performant way.

So far i have something like this, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Even if it did work, I think I'd have trouble with duplicate categories if multiple children of the same parent category are selected, and it might go on longer than it needs to if it's looping over an array that it's also adding to on every loop?

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :recursively_add_parents

  # ...

  def recursively_add_parents
    self.categories.each do |t|
      # recursively add taxonomy parents in here?
      self.categories << Category.find(t.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I would personally drop the gem and just create a foreign key pointing back to the id column (all in the categories table). Then, I would put this logic in a service object instead of a callback. To get all the parents, you could get the parent category of self until it is `nil`. Just make sure you set the `optional` tag in `has_many :categories, option: true` on your relationship.

Comment: yep! that aspect is working great, and this gem does work by using a parent_id column and an optional self-association, it just gives me useful helpers on top of that. sadly enforcing that something in a child category must also be in all that category's parents isn't one of them.